# How to call jquery plugging for dynamic html elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, plugins, jquery-plugins

I'm binding some data dynamically to the html. While I bind this I have to call a function to process the value of the same html elements. See the code:

```
$.each(data, function(key, value) {
    htmlData += '<div class="large-1 infographic-box border_right merged-top pull-left widget-data" >';
          $.each(value,function(dKey,dValue){

                htmlData += '<span id="'+dKey+'['+ key +']"  class="'+dKey+' value widget-data" data-value="'+dValue+'">'+ dValue  +'</span>';
                })
                htmlData += '<span class="headline">'+ monthNames[parseInt(key)-1] +'</span>'+
                                 '</div>';
            });
                htmlData += '</div>';
                 $('.transaction-section').html(htmlData);
    $('.widget-data').each(function(){
            var value = $(this).data('value');
            var index = $(this).attr('id');
            $(this).siPrifixx(value,{
                maxDigits: 4,
                seperator: true,
                decimal: 1,
                popUp: true,
                countUp:index
           })
     });
```

To this html I have to call a function on `$('.widget-data').each(function()` some things. But when I call it in side the / out the side the block its not trigerring. How can I do this?

My scripts inside the `$(document).ready()`, still its not get change, I need to process `dValue` in my `siPrifixx`, its need to humanize.But this thinks, I do get values, but the `siPrifixx` not getting fired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a way to call the function its works for me.

```
$.each($(htmlData).find('.widget-data'), function(){
            var value = $(this).data('value');
            var index = $(this).attr('id');
            $(this).siPrifixx(value,{
                maxDigits: 4,
                seperator: true,
                decimal: 1,
                popUp: true,
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `delegate`

```
$('body').delegate('.widget-data','click',function() {
     //Your scripts
});
```

Comment: I fire  on load,not on click!

Comment: so you can just change 'click; to 'ready', like $(document).ready() or $(function(){ $('.widget-data').each(function() ......})

Comment: I have been run my scripts inside the  `$(document).ready()` ,still its not get change, I need to process `dValue` in my `siPrifixx` ,its need to humanize.But this thinks,I do get values,but the `siPrifixx` not getting fired.

Comment: Do you need `load` or `each` ? If you need each use ``each`` instead of `click`.

Comment: `each` is better than load! I have found a solution for call the function.Since having trouble to bind the return values.Now plunging is process the dValue.But the process data not getting bind

Answer (score 0):

Use [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to jquery

1. Select a dom element father(this element cannot be change)
2. Call event to listen
3. List element to listen(this element can be change)

   $( "table" ).on( "click", "td", function() {
     //code
   });